# use of middleware in custom package devlopment in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, package, laravel-7, laravel-8

I want to build packages in which I want to make middleware which validate data from different services(different project) by just installing that package.
what is a step to making this type of command and publish in any project?
I read the document. I understand that how to make view(loadViewFrom), route(loadRouteFrom) but didn't find any methods for middleware like loadViewFrom, loadRouteFrom. and how to publish that packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your service provider file you add a variation of the following:

```
use Illuminate\Routing\Router;
use yourpackageauthor\YourPackageName\App\Http\Middleware\YourMiddlwareClass;

...


    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(Router $router)
    {
        $router->middlewareGroup('yourMiddlwareName', [YourMiddlewareClass::class]);
    }
```

- For reference see:
  https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-blocker/blob/master/src/LaravelBlockerServiceProvider.php